# Receber Token através de WebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth2, token

Pessoal existe alguma maneira de eu gerar um token através de uma WebRequest? Pois toda vez que vou utilizar a função do Google Drive eu preciso abrir A pagina de autenticação somente para ela gerar o Token de acesso, ha alguma forma de eu fazer isso por WebRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            var clientrest = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            var requestToken = new RestRequest("oauth/token", Method.POST);
            requestToken.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            requestToken.AddParameter("username", model.Login);
            requestToken.AddParameter("password", model.Senha);
            var responseToken = clientrest.Execute<TokenViewModel>(requestToken);
            responseToken.Data.access_token; // acesso ao token
```

usei restsharp https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp

Comment: este "client" seria oque?

Comment: ignora foi erro na hora de colar ja editei